# Как запустить .jar?

Tags: java

Скачал из Интернета [программу](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jarbundler/) в виде .*jar* и теперь никак не могу запустить ее. Двойной клик не запускает (свои *jar-файлы* я запускаю без проблем). Пробую через командную строку

```
java -jar jarbundler-2.2.0.jar
```

получаю ошибку:

> no main manifest attribute, in
> jarbundler-2.2.0.jar

Весь Интернет переполнен подобной жалобой, но я так и не понял как все таки запустить его? Понял что надо прописать как-то в **MANIFEST.MF** путь к файлу с функцией **main()**.
Ребят, как-то последовательно может кто объяснить что делать? Работаю в Mac OS.

Comment: Абсолютный путь к файлу напиши

Comment: [может поможет][1]
  [1]: http://informagen.com/JarBundler/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще-то это не запускаемая программа, а task для [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Это можно увидеть из описания:

> **JarBundler is a feature-rich Apache ANT task** that can create Mac OS X Application Bundles from a list of JAR files and a main class name. It also provides fine-grained control over the Mac OS X Application Bundle options and application behavior.

Так что запустить это не получится. Для того, чтобы работать с этой библиотекой нужно организовать сборку ant'ом. Пример использования этой либы есть вот на [этой](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/index.html) странице.

Comment: > вот на этой странице

Собственно, вот и моя ссылка. :)

Comment: @samoilow, суть не в ссылке, а то что это не программа, а библиотека.

Comment: Ну да, просто я не стал отвечать, а просто дал ссылку, ибо не знаком с Java.

Answer (score 4):

Либо явно указывайте Main-класс

```
java -cp MyJar.jar com.example.Main
```

Или так:

```
java -classpath MyJar.jar com.example.Main
```

Либо в jar (в файл META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) строку:

```
Main-Class: com.example.Main
```

**UPD**

Ну точно, а я подумал тут пример запускают на java какой-то.

Короче так в том же архиве есть пример (*jarbundler-2.2.0.zip\jarbundler-2.2.0\example*), вот его можно собрать. Примерно так:

```
ant jar
```

после сборки появится jar файл Hello World.jar, вот его можно будет запустить.

Но **JarBundler** вообще не для этого. Он помогает собрать специальное приложение для Mac. Чтобы собрать пример нужно так делать:

```
ant complex
```